Is there an integer that serves as the short leg of a primitive Pythagorean triple, the long leg of another, and the hypotenuse of a third?
A primitive pythagorean triple is of the form $(a,b,c)$ where $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$. If we list these three numbers such that $a<b<c$, is there an integer
$x$ where $x$ appears in all three "slots" once?
Example: $13$ appears in the third slot $(5$-$12$-$13)$ and first $(13$-$84$-$85)$ but not in the second.
Note: $x$ must be a part of the primitive Pythagorean triple, we cannot have something like $15$-$20$-$25$

Didn't check my answer well enough but (65,72,97),(33,65,73),(16,63,65) is a close one

Well I do know that x is odd, so that narrows my search down by 50%

@uggupuggu Also , $x$ must be of the form $4k+1$ and not divisible by $3$.

@Peter - Indeed, $x$ must not be divisible by any $4k+3$ (by the known properties of Gaussian primes, and the fact that the sought Gaussian integer must not have ordinary integer factors).

According to this snippet I wrote, the least such $x$ if you drop the gcd condition is $x=15$, viz.  the triples $(15,,20,,17)$, $(8,,15,,17)$ & $(9,,12,,15)$. If you demand all three triples are co-prime as per this snippet, you get @MichaelLugo's solution with $x=221$ as the minimal $x$.

@J.G. I suspected 221 was minimal but didn't see a good way to prove it!  Thanks.

This question was mentioned in Zach Wissner-Gross's "Fiddler on the Proof" substack: https://thefiddler.substack.com/p/how-high-can-you-jump

Not going to lie, this has the potential to be in an AIME 10 to 15 question.

One can easily verify that $(221, 24420, 24421)$, $(60,221,229)$, and $(21,220,221)$ are Pythagorean triples - this is an answer.
How did I find it?
A primitive Pythagorean triple is of the form $(m^2 - n^2, 2mn, m^2 + n^2)$, with $m$ and $n$ coprime and not both odd.  But there's no guarantee that the legs come out in the right order.
Since $m$ and $n$ have opposite parity, $m^2 + n^2$ must be odd (and actually of the form $4k+1$).   But $2mn$ is even.  So any such number will be a sum of two squares, and also a difference of two squares in two different ways, one of which has $m^2 - n^2 < 2mn$ and one of which has $m^2 - n^2 > 2mn$.  Furthermore, by mod 4 considerations, in both expressions we must have $m$ odd and $n$ even.
Next, we want to figure out the number of ways to write a positive integer as a difference of squares.  Each expression of an odd integer as a difference of squares corresponds to a factorization.  For example consider
$$33 = 17^2 - 16^2 = (17- 16)(17 +16) = 1 \times 33$$
and
$$33 = 7^2 - 4^2 = (7-4)(7+4) = 3 \times 11$$
In fact the number of ways to write a positive odd integer as a difference of squares is exactly half its number of factors.  (This is not a complete proof of this fact.)
So the number we're looking for must:

be of form 4k+1
have at least four factors (so it can be written as a difference of two squares in at least two ways)
be a sum of two squares.
The integers which are sums of two squares are exactly those where no prime of form $4k+3$ appears to an odd power (this is a classical result in number theory).

The easiest way to get four factors is a product of two distinct primes.  We want to avoid primes of form $4k+3$, so we take $5 \times 13 = 65$.  Then we have $65 = 33^2 - 32^2$ giving the triple $(65, 2112, 2113)$ and $65 = 9^2 - 4^2$ gfiving the triple $(65, 72, 97)$.  So this doesn't work because $65$ falls into the "low" slot both times.
Similarly $85 = 5 \times 17$ doesn't work.  You need the two primes to be relatively close together in order to get $m^2 - n^2 > 2mn$, which we need.
So look at $13 \times 17 = 221$:

$221 = 111^2 - 110^2$ gives the triple $(221, 24420, 24421)$
$221 = 15^2 - 2^2$ gives the triple $(60, 221, 229)$
$221 = 10^2 + 11^2$ gives the triple $(21, 220, 221)$.


very nice!! this is increasingly looking to me like a fun homework problem for the upcoming year

Now , my routine worked better. For at least the $20$ following numbers there are solutions using $a,b\le 400$ : $$[221, 325, 377, 425, 493, 629, 697, 725, 1885, 2405, 2665, 3145, 3445, 3485, 3965, 4505, 4745, 5185, 5785, 6205]$$

The largest I found in this range is : $98605$

@BenjaminDickman I enjoyed figuring it out - I don't know if your students would!

Also $221=5^2+14^2$ gives the triple $(140,171,221)$.

Given $x\in\mathbb N$, let $r$ be the number of ordered primitive Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a=x$, let $s$ be the number of triples with $b=x$, and let $t$ be the number of triples with $c=x$. For example $x=221$ has $(r,s,t)=(1,1,2)$. If $rst\neq0$, i.e. if $x$ is a solution to the OP, the most common values for small $x$ are $(r,s,t)=(1,1,2)$, $(3,1,4)$, and $(7,1,8)$. Then I found a few $x$ around $200,!000$ with $(r,s,t)=(6,2,8)$, such as $x=160225$:

$$(160225, 12836025312, 12836025313) \ (160225, 75952728, 75952897) \ (160225, 44415168, 44415457) \ (160225, 20537328, 20537953) \ (160225, 15262392, 15263233) \ (160225, 238392, 287233)$$ $$(68712, 160225, 174337) \ (19248, 160225, 161377)$$ $$(33217, 156744, 160225) \ (56257, 150024, 160225) \ (66913, 145584, 160225) \ (93247, 130296, 160225) \ (86784, 134687, 160225) \ (63504, 147103, 160225) \ (59736, 148673, 160225) \ (25536, 158177, 160225)$$

I might conjecture that $t$ is always a power of $2$, and that $r+s=t$.

I've confirmed part of my conjecture: If $x>1$ is odd, then (regardless of whether $rst=0$) we have $r+s=2^{k-1}$ where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $x$. This follows from considering factorizations of $x=m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)$, and noticing that GCD$(m,n)=1$ is equivalent to GCD$(m-n,m+n)=1$ (given that $x$ is odd). So $r+s$ is the number of such coprime factorizations, $x=uv$ where GCD$(u,v)=1$. -- The other part of the conjecture remains: $r+s=t$ (assuming $t\neq0$)?

Another conjecture is $r\geq s$. I verified this by computer for all odd $x<100,!000$, and for all even $x\leq1,!000,!000$ except $x=4$. (And this is excluding $x=1$, because the triple $0^2+1^2=1^2$ violates the OP's condition $a<b<c$.)

Analyzing the problem in terms of Gaussian primes, I found that $t=0$ if $x$ has any prime factor $p\equiv3\bmod4$. And obviously $t=0$ if $x$ is even. Otherwise, $x$ is a product of primes $p\equiv1\bmod4$, and $t=2^{k-1}$ where $k$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $x$.

@Peter You might consider adding the sequence of integers from your comment yesterday to the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences! It doesn't seem to be there yet.

This is possible! For example, it occurs with $1885$:
$$1885^2 + 10428^2 = 10597^2$$
$$1692^2 + 1885^2 = 2533^2$$
$$427^2 + 1836^2 = 1885^2$$
This was found through a Python search generated and executed in ChatGPT (link).

Edit: Once one has found such solutions, it is possible to search for related literature more effectively. For example, see:

Fässler, Albert. "Multiple Pythagorean number triples." The American mathematical monthly 98.6 (1991): 505-517. Link.

On p. 509 part (d)(1) begins with $1105$. Checking WolframAlpha, we can use the query:

solve over Z+: a^2 + 1105^2 = c^2 && gcd(a,1105,c) = 1

to see that there are no solutions for which $1105$ is the smallest number in a primitive Pythagorean triple. The next number listed in the aforelinked is $1885$, which (as indicated above) gives a solution. This can be verified in WolframAlpha; the first result for each query (linked with the corresponding letter) is precisely the solution provided above this Edit.
For a:

solve over Z+: m^2 + 1885^2 = n^2 && gcd(m,1885,n) = 1 && 1885<m<n

For b:

solve over Z+: m^2 + 1885^2 = n^2 && gcd(m,1885,n) = 1 && m<1885<n

For c:

solve over Z+: m^2 + n^2 = 1885^2 && gcd(m,1885,n) = 1 && m<n<1885

